# Mudar timezone javascript

Tags: javascript, data

Tenho uma aplicação hospedada no heroku. Então, cada data que é gerada lá na api e retornada para o front, sempre retorna com um dia de atraso. Já meu front, está hospedado na Hostinger, então, acaba conflitando as datas por causa do timezone.

Eu tentei isso:

```
document.getElementById("data").addEventListener("input", function(){
    var data = document.getElementById("data").value;

  var d = new Date(data);

  var options = {week: "long", year: "numeric", month: "long", day: "numeric", timezone: "America/Sao_Paulo"}

  var year = d.getFullYear();
  var month = (d.getMonth() < 10) ? "0" + d.getMonth() : d.getMonth();
  var day = ((d.getDate() + 1) < 10) ? "0" + (d.getDate() + 1) : (d.getDate() + 1);
  var hour = d.getHours();
  var minutes = d.getMinutes();

    //options.timezone = 'America/Santa_Isabel';

  var dataFormatada = new Date(Date.UTC(year, month, day, hour, minutes, 0));
  var dataExtensa = dataFormatada.toLocaleString('pt-BR', options);
  var dataSimples = dataFormatada.toLocaleString({timezone: 'America/Sao_Paulo'});
  document.getElementById("dataSimples").innerHTML = "Data simples " + dataSimples;
})

<input type="date" placeholder="Data" id="data"/>
<p id="dataSimples"></p>
```

Mas não funciona. Eu preciso que qualquer data que seja criada, seja sempre o timezone do brasil, então, toda a data passada para a api ou criada lá, tenha esse timezone como default. Alguma sugestão para resolver isso?

Comment: Você sabe se o servidor é UTC Time? Existe uma biblioteca js que permite manipulação dos objetos data: http://momentjs.com. Mais especificamente essa função: http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/ mas para utilizar, você deve saber se é gravado em UTC pois a base dele é UTC.

Comment: Realmente não sei te dizer, nathalia. Justamente por isso que estou optando pelo js puro a fim de realmente persistir essa questão de timezone. O servidor é o Heroku.

Comment: Esse link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33995194/what-timezone-is-heroku-server-using (em inglês) informa que o default dele é UTC. Fala também que existe a possibilidade de alterar essa configuração. Desculpe, não sou muito entendedora do heroku e para fazer conversão de timezone, sempre temos que saber qual timezone está voltando.

Comment: Nathalia, vc é um anjo. Aplica a configuração que existe nessa resposta que vc mencionou e funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado. Pessoas como vc mudam o mundo positivamente!!!!!!

Comment: Que bom Felipe, posso colocar então esse item na resposta e fechamos essa pergunta?

Comment: Claro. Pode sim e marco como a resposta correta. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por padrão o heroku utiliza o UTC timezone.

Você pode trocar o timezone padrão do servidor utilizando a configuração:

```
heroku config:add TZ="America/Chicago"
```

A configuração também pode ser feita pelo dashboard.

**FONTE**
[StackOverflow (em inglês)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33995194/what-timezone-is-heroku-server-using)